# MongoDB: Trying to updating a field based on count of matched criteria in nested subdocument

Tags: mongodb, count, mongodb-query, match, aggregate

I have the below nested array of documents and trying to update the "readCounter" (which is number). I want to set the "readCounter" to the count of documents matching condition: "userId": "naveen" and "otherUserIds.otherUserId": "ashwini" and "messages.sentBy": "ashwini". In the below case, the readCounter for the mentioned condition should be set to "2". Please help me with a MongoDB query to update the "readCounter".

I used the below query to update, but it is giving wrong result.

```
AllChats.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                userId: details.userId,
                "otherUserIds.otherUserId": details.otherUserId,
                "messages.sentBy": details.otherUserId
            }
        },
            {
                $set: { $count: "otherUserIds.$.msgReadCounter"}
            }
    ]
);
```

Below is the database data:

```
AllChats = [{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f43fb76167f53d3d46b52ef"),
        "userId" : "naveen",
        "otherUserIds" : [
                {
                        "otherUserId" : "ashwini",
                        "readCounter" : 0,
                        "messages" : [
                                {
                                        "msg" : "Hi Naveen",
                                        "sentBy" : "ashwini"
                                },
                                {
                                        "msg" : "Hi Ashwini",
                                        "sentBy" : "naveen"
                                },
                                {
                                        "msg" : "How are you today",
                                        "sentBy" : "ashwini"
                                },
                                {
                                        "msg" : "I'm good",
                                        "sentBy" : "naveen"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "otherUserId" : "testuser",
                        "readCounter" : 0,
                        "messages" : [
                                {
                                        "msg" : "Hi naveen",
                                        "sentBy" : "testuser"
                                },
                                {
                                        "msg" : "Im good",
                                        "sentBy" : "naveen"
                                },
                                {
                                        "msg" : "how are you today",
                                        "sentBy" : "testuser"
                                },
                                {
                                        "msg" : "how are you testuser",
                                        "sentBy" : "naveen"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f440e5e167f53d3d46b52f0"),
        "userId" : "ashwini",
        "otherUserIds" : [
                {
                        "otherUserId" : "naveen",
                        "readCounter" : 0,
                        "message" : [
                                {
                                        "msg" : "Hi Naveen",
                                        "sentBy" : "ashwini"
                                },
                                {
                                        "msg" : "Hi Ashwini",
                                        "sentBy" : "naveen"
                                },
                                {
                                        "msg" : "How are you today",
                                        "sentBy" : "ashwini"
                                },
                                {
                                        "msg" : "I'm good",
                                        "sentBy" : "naveen"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself but it's expensive. It involves two separate database queries, so I would be open to better solutions.

```
try{
        let counter = await AllChats.aggregate([
            {$match: {userId: details.userId}},
            {$unwind: "$otherUserIds"},
            {$match: {"otherUserIds.otherUserId": details.otherUserId}},
            {$unwind: "$otherUserIds.messages"},
            {$match: {"otherUserIds.messages.sentBy": details.otherUserId}},
            {$count: "counter"}
        ]);

        console.log(counter[0]);
        if(counter[0] !== undefined){
        await AllChats.findOneAndUpdate(
            {userId: details.userId}, 
            {$set: {"otherUserIds.$[elem].msgReadCounter": counter[0].counter}},
            {arrayFilters: [{"elem.otherUserId": details.otherUserId}]}
            );
            console.log("Updated message read counter");
        }
    } catch(err){

        console.log(err);
}
```